# I just add two alias name for the same remote repo on Git. How can I delete one of them? Here is my code

Tags: git

I initialize the git on my local first. Then I add and commit to my index file. After, I create an online/remote repo. Now when I used git remote add origin ur it's fine but then

```
git push -u origin master
```

I got an error

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
<code>

git push --set-upstream origin master

</code>
```

I don't know what `--set-upstream` this means
but then I wrote command `git remote add reactorigin url`
then `git push -u reactorigin master`... It works and It was published on my Remote repo. But when i use command `git remote -v`

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ?https://gitlab.com/vinodthapa/reactjs.git (fetch)
origin  ?https://gitlab.com/vinodthapa/reactjs.git (push)
reactorigin     https://gitlab.com/vinodthapa/reactjs.git (fetch)
reactorigin     https://gitlab.com/vinodthapa/reactjs.git (push)
```

Now I want to delete the alias name origin and want only `reactorigin` as an alias name to my remote url. I tried `rm` but it's not working.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas for formatting my question. Could you tell me where I did wrong on my above code?

Comment: Try `git remote remove origin`.

Comment: Guys, It works thanks to @ElpieKay <code> git remote remove origin <code> It's work and I delete the Origin alias name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer here is the code, First

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ?https://gitlab.com/vinodthapa/reactjs.git (fetch)
origin  ?https://gitlab.com/vinodthapa/reactjs.git (push)
reactorigin     https://gitlab.com/vinodthapa/reactjs.git (fetch)
reactorigin     https://gitlab.com/vinodthapa/reactjs.git (push)
```

then for deleting the origin alias name I wrote

```
$ git remote remove origin
```

Now the final output is

```
$ git remote -v
reactorigin     https://gitlab.com/vinodthapa/reactjs.git (fetch)
reactorigin     https://gitlab.com/vinodthapa/reactjs.git (push
```

Comment: You had selected the right answer initially. Consider re-selecting it.

Answer (score 1):

The '`?`' (`origin  ?https://...`) in front of the URL is suspicious.

Try rewriting that URL with:

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/vinodthapa/reactjs.git
```

Then try again:

```
git push -u origin master
```

It is best to keep the remote named "`origin`", as it is the default name used for commands like `git push`.

You can therefore delete the other one with:

```
git remote remove reactorigin
```

If you had already deleted `origin`, you can rename the other one to `origin`:

```
git remote rename reactorigin origin
```

Comment: I already set the alias name as reactorigin and its working perfect. I just want to delete one extra that is Origin one. But now I deleted by using it remote remove origin

Comment: @UIDeveloperNepal Keep origin, delete the other one (reactorigin): I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: ok sure But I already deleted. So, I have to now rename the reactorigin to origin.

Comment: @UIDeveloperNepal OK. I have edited the answer to include the rename command.